# No cargan las imágenes

Tags: javascript, css, img

No me cargan las imágenes de la pagina la primera vez que las abro en gitgub pages, la segunda vez que entro ya cargan bien, no se bien a que se deba, e probado:
cambiar ruta absoluta por relativa,
ponerle un setTimeout,
adjunto codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Personales</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="global">
        <!--Cabecera-->
        <header>
            <div class="t_personales">
               <h2>Retratos personales</h2> 
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="personas.html">ATRÁS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="imagen_pe_b">
            <img src="img/personal1.jpg">
            <img src="img/personal2.jpg">
            <img src="img/personal3.jpg">
            <img src="img/personal4.jpeg">
        </div>
        <br><br><br>
        <div class="imagen_pe_c">
            <img src="img/personal1c.jpeg">
            <img src="img/personal2c.jpeg">
            <img src="img/personal3c.jpeg">
            <img src="img/personal4c.jpeg">
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="foot">
        ==============LimbertArt ================ &copy;
    </footer>
</body>
</html>

.imagen_pe_b{
    display: block !important;
}
.imagen_pe_c{
    display: block !important;
}
.imagen_pa_b{
    display: block !important;
}
.imagen_pa_c{
    display: block !important;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tambien eh probado cargar el archivo main.js al  principio y al final,
disminuir la cantidad de fotos a 4 por cada bxslider,
ponerle un display: block !important; a cada bxslider en el styles.css.
Les agradezco de antemano
ESte es el codigo javascript..gracias..faltaron 4 bxslider mas en el javascript..no me deja poner mas codigo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".imagen_pe_b").bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
      captions: true,
      slideWidth: 'auto'
    });
    $(".imagen_pe_c").bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
      captions: true,
      slideWidth: 'auto'
    });
    $(".imagen_pa_b").bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
      captions: true,
      slideWidth: 'auto'
    });
    $(".imagen_pa_c").bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
      captions: true,
      slideWidth: 'auto'
    });

    $(".imagen_f_b").bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
      captions: true,
      slideWidth: 'auto'
    });
    $(".imagen_f_c").bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
      captions: true,
      slideWidth: 'auto'
    });
    
  },100);
})
```

Comment: Puedes agregar tu código de JavaScript también

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ ok ya lo modifico

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir tu repositorio de github?

Comment: @cardosource ya lo pongo

Comment: https://github.com/LimberMolina16/art

Comment: Asegúrate que las imágenes están en una carpeta llamada img que esta situada en la misma carpeta que el html.